# Laravel - Update dynamic form fields in database

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, dynamic, eloquent

I have a dynamic form where the user should be able to add or remove fields while editing.

I am able to update the exact number fields that are in the database table. But what I want is if a user clicked a `'Delete Subject'` and `'Update'` buttons, I want that entire row deleted from the database.

And, if he added a subject by clicking `'Add another Subject'` the form and clicked `'Update'` I want those subjects added. What am I missing here?

Note:  I built a One-to-Many relation between **New** and **Subjects**, where a New has many subjects and many subjects belong to a New (It works fine).

**My form** looks like this
[image: Dynamic Form Fields - Subjects]

**New Model**

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'address'];
public function subjects() {
    return $this->hasMany(Subjects::class, 'new_id');
}
```

**Subjects Model**

```
protected $fillable = ['new_id', 'sub_code', 'sub_name', 'sub_img'];

public function subs(){
    return $this->belongsTo(New::class, 'new_id');
}
```

**Create Method**

```
public function create(Request $request, New $new){
$new = New::FindorFail($id)
$subjects= [];
        $sub_images = $request->file('sub_img');
        $sub_name = $request->sub_name;

        for ($i=0; $i < count(request('sub_code')); ++$i) 
        {
        $subjects = new Subjects;
        $subjecs->sub_code = request('sub_code')[$i];
        $subjects->sub_name = request('sub_name')[$i];
        $sub_img_name = uniqid() . '.' . $sub_images[$i]->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $sub_images[$i]->move(public_path('/images/'), $sub_img_name);            
        $subjects->sub_img = '/images/'.$sub_img_name;
        $new->subjects()->save($subjects);
        }
     }
```

**Update Method**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
$new=New::FindOrFail($id)
$subjects = Subjects::with(['subs'])->where('new_id', $new->id)->get();
$new->update($request->all());

$i=0;
foreach( $subjects as $new_subjects)
   {
    $sub_images =request()->file('sub_img');    
    $sub_name = request('sub_name');
    if(isset($sub_images[$i]))
      {
       $pathToStore = public_path('images');    
       if($request->hasFile('sub_img') && isset($sub_images[$i]))
         {
          $sub_img_name = uniqid() . '.' . $sub_images[$i]->getClientOriginalExtension();
           $sub_images[$i]->move(public_path('/images/'), $sub_img_name);            
           $new_subjects->sub_img = '/images/'.$sub_img_name;

           $new_subjects->sub_code = request('sub_code')[$i];
           $new_subjects->sub_name = request('sub_name')[$i];
           $new_subjects->sub_img = "images/{$sub_img_name}";
           $i++;
           $new->subjects()->save($new_subjects);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Subjects Database**

I want this table row be updated (added or deleted) after user edit the form.

[image: NEW can have many subjects.]

Comment: what is the error you getting?

Comment: No errors. Update executed successfully but number of Subjects are not updated in database.

Comment: Where are you trying to save new subjects amount into database?

Comment: I have ``Subjects`` Table that has ``id``, ``new_id``, ``sub_code``,  ``sub_name``, ``sub_img`` where ``new_id`` is referenced ID of student. (updated question - see screenshot)

Comment: Do you want to do something like this? [Create dynamic forms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Efr7SUrBUQw)

Comment: @universal - Can you share you view blade with me, I have similar problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with Laravel, I think the problem is that you call the Product model instead of the New model so maybe you need to fix it.

you reference the New model :

`public function subs(){
    enter code herereturn $this->belongsTo(New::class, 'new_id');
}`

then you use the wrong model Product :

`$new=Product::FinOrFail($id)`

Another thing is to double check the `fillable` attribute within the Subject model also you can write the update action and do something like

Comment: That's ``New`` model & corrected. I tried 
``Subjects::UpdateOrCreate(['new_id' => $new->id],['sub_code'=>$new_subjects->sub_code],['sub_name' => $new_subjects->col_name], ['sub_img' => $new_subjects->col_img]);``
But didn't work. I think there is a method to Delete/Create/Update table data, which I'm missing. (Question updated)