# Laravel - Save multiple field values in json/array in a column

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, dynamic

I have 3 form fields `name, address, profile_photo`. I want to save there 3 fields in json/array format in a single column so that I can retrieve it later in view blade.

**My form looks like this**
[image: Dynamic fields]

**I tried**

```
$customer_details= new Customer;
  {

   $profile_photo = $request->file('profile_photo');
   for ($i=0; $i < count(request('profile_photo')); $i++) {

   $pro_fileExt =  $profile_photo[$i]->getClientOriginalExtension();
   $pro_fileNameToStore = time().'.'.$pro_fileExt;

   $pro_pathToStore = public_path('images');

   Image::make($profile_photo[$i])->save($pro_pathToStore . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $pro_fileNameToStore);
   $profile_ph = '/images/'.$pro_fileNameToStore; }

   $cust_details=json_encode(request(['name', 'address', $profile_ph]));
   $customer_details->details = $cust_details;
   $customer_details->save();
  }
```

With this profile_photo is not saved but other data are saved as:

```
{"name":["john","Sam"],"address":["CA","FL"]}
```

How can I save all there fields including profile_photo and show each details distinctly later on view blade?

Comment: Hi, Why do you want to save 3 fields in json/array format in a single column? Really I dont understand that.

Comment: Previously I saved in individual columns/rows. But later, I couldn't update (add/remove) data. So

Comment: Are you using mysql?

Comment: Yes. That column is ``text``. What I really want is option to update (dynamically add or remove customer details upon updating)

Comment: That is really simple with laravel.  Here you have an explanation in only 11 minutes. [Laravel 5.4 Tutorial | CRUD (Update) Operation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_O6KNdxioak) .    Also you have [The Full Serie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4T7jOSxus90&list=PLe30vg_FG4OQz1yZq0z19ZuWD_C3MZbA4)

Comment: I can update single row data easily. But my real problem is [Update dynamic fields] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345081/laravel-update-dynamic-form-fields-in-database)

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you.

```
    $customer_details = new Customer;

    $profile_photo = $request->file('profile_photo');
    $profile_ph = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count(request('profile_photo')); $i++) {

        $pro_fileExt = $profile_photo[$i]->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $pro_fileNameToStore = time() . '.' . $pro_fileExt;

        $pro_pathToStore = public_path('images');

        Image::make($profile_photo[$i])->save($pro_pathToStore . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $pro_fileNameToStore);
        $profile_ph[$i] = '/images/' . $pro_fileNameToStore;
    }

    $data = [
        'name' => $request->name,
        'address' => $request->address,
        'profile_ph' => $profile_ph
    ];

    $customer_details->details = json_encode($data);

    $customer_details->save();
```

The `details` column should be `text` if you are using mysql.

Comment: Ya. It's ``text``. But data are saved as ``{"name":["name1","name2"],"address":["addr1","addr2"],"profile_photo":"\/images\/432rd-1522133964.PNG"}``

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$names = $request->input('name');
$addresses = $request->input('address');
$profile_photos = $request->file('profile_photo');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($names); $i++) {
    $customer_details = new Customer;
    $pro_fileExt = $profile_photos[$i]->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $pro_fileNameToStore = time() . '.' . $pro_fileExt;

    $pro_pathToStore = public_path('images');

    Image::make($profile_photos[$i])->save($pro_pathToStore . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $pro_fileNameToStore);
    $profile_ph = '/images/' . $pro_fileNameToStore;

    $cust_details = json_encode([
        'name' => $names[$i],
        'address' => $addresses[$i],
        'profile_photo' => $profile_ph,
    ]);

    $customer_details->details = $cust_details;
    $customer_details->save();
}
```

Comment: It saved as ``{"name":["John","Sam"],"address":["CA","FL"],"profile_photo":"\/images\/32fdwf  fds f-john-1522133136.PNG"}``. Ican't save 2 images while there are 2 names & addresses.

Comment: @universal do you want to have each of these details in a separate row in the database, or all in the same row?

Comment: I want whatever. But I should be able to add/delete records later upon updating.  I saved in separate rows before, but I couldn't achieve that, So I decided this approach. BTW I saved in the same format as above,

Answer (score 0):

Try this with single database query

```
$profile_photo = $request->file('profile_photo');
$finalData = [];
$names = [];
$addresses = [];
$images = [];
for ($i=0; $i < count(request('profile_photo')); $i++) {
  $pro_fileExt =  $profile_photo[$i]->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $pro_fileNameToStore = time().'.'.$pro_fileExt;
  $pro_pathToStore = public_path('images');
  Image::make($profile_photo[$i])->save($pro_pathToStore . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $pro_fileNameToStore);
  $profile_ph = '/images/'.$pro_fileNameToStore; }
  $names[] = $request->input('name');
  $addresses[] = $request->input('address');
  $images[] = $profile_ph;
}
 $cust_details=json_encode(['name' => $names, 'address' => $addresses, 'images' => $images]);
 $customer_details->insert($cust_details);
```